How to debug HTTP 400 Bad Request errors in django?
I have an app with React frontend and Django backend. I'm trying to make a POST request from my react client but I get "Bad Request" error. I checked my request url and it matches with my api url. Therefore I believe the error has to do with the data I pass. How can I debug this error to learn more about it?
Here are the necessary code parts:
models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BatchChain(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()


class Batch(models.Model): # This is the model I'm trying to POST
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="batches_from_products")
    chain = models.ForeignKey(BatchChain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

serializers.py
class BatchPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Batch
        fields = ["id", "product", "chain"]

views.py
class BatchListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BatchPostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        batches = Batch.objects.filter(product__owner=user)

        return Batch.objects.filter(chain__in=batches.values_list("chain"))

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if serializer.is_valid() is False:
            return Response({'Message': 'Serializer is not valid'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if Batch.objects.filter(chain=self.request.data["chain"]).exists():
            return Response({'Message': 'You can not create a second batch with same chain'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

        serializer.save()

api/urls.py
...
path("batches/", views.BatchListCreate.as_view(), name="batch-list-create"), # all calls to /api/ are directed to this folder
...

frontend
api
        .post("/api/batches/", { product: batchProduct, chain: chain })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.status === 201) {
                navigate("/chains")
            }
            else {
                alert("Parti oluşturulamadı")
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            alert(err)
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setIsLoading(false)
        })

My log file only logs this output:
Bad Request: /api/batches/
"POST /api/batches/ HTTP/1.1" 400 127


You can try and do the request using postman

Thanks, that helped a lot. Apparrently, I was passing objects for foreign keys instead of their pk's.
